# how can I push function into an array in c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Lets say I have function of type void in c++

eg:

```
void fun1(); 
void fun2();
void fun3();
```

how can I push these function into an array?
eg:

```
array[0] = fun1();
array[1] = fun2();
array[2] = fun3();
```

Comment: The type of these functions is `void(*)()`, not `void`.

Comment: One does not "push" onto an array...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use function pointers in C.

```
void (*array[2])();
array[0] = fun1;
array[1] = fun2;
```

Or `std::function` in C++:

```
std::function<void(void)> fn1 = fun1;
std::function<void(void)> fn2 = fun2;
std::vector<std::function<void(void)> > v;
v.push_back(fn1);
v.push_back(fn2);
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII And `C` in tags.

Comment: And C as a tag. std::function is really good, but classic function pointer would do.

Comment: `std::function` works just fine, but there's nothing wrong with this answer or raw function pointers. You are being anal @Richard.

Comment: Some prefer to use function pointers if they won't be storing anything like functors as well. `std::function` is a bit overkill in those cases.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I hope the edit finally satisfies your fastidious taste...

Comment: @Richard you are generalizing. That's bad. One size doesn't fit all, and just because you have an electric screwdriver doesn't mean you have to *always* use it. Sometimes the old screwdriver works just fine and the electric one is overkill.

Comment: @H2CO3 thank you for the answer. That was exactly what I was looking for. Just curious why my question was down voted?

Comment: @goonda I guess because it fits the "shows no research effort" clause in the FAQ.

Comment: @goonda because it wasn't clear. Are you using C, C++, do you need functors, and what exactly is `array`?

Comment: @Xaqq Don't vandalize my answer.

Comment: Adding a link to an alternative solution is not vandalizing -_-. Its called improving :)

Comment: @Xaqq Removing good code is absolutely vandalizing - adding a link (which could break in the future) to the documentation was pointless.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I didnt remove any code. Just added a link to the official documentation of std::function. Maybe it's because we edited at the time.

Comment: @Xaqq Please look at the edit history and don't deny having done what you have done. Your edit removed all my example code related to `std::function`. Perhaps it was unintentional, but it did happen for sure.

Comment: @Xaqq H2CO3 is correct. [Here's your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2223161) - it clearly gets rid of his code.

Comment: Well, there was no code when I begin editing the answer. Bad timing then :)

Comment: @H2CO3 when I try to compile using std::funtion<void(void)> compiler error occurs saying : function was not declared in this scope. Is it because I have old c++?mine is 4.7.2

Comment: @H2CO3 u r awesomeeeeeeee

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an interface pattern.

i.e.

```
class CallBackInterface {
   public:
      virtual void CallBack();
};

class CallBack1 : public CallBackInterface{
   public:
      virtual void CallBack();
   private:
      int someData;
};
```

... etc

Then create the array using the base type

```
CallBackInterface arr[] = 
{
   CallBack1(),
   callBack2(5, "Hello"),
   ...
};
```

Each object can carry around whatever payload it wants - you can then do

```
arr[1].CallBack();
```

To call the function

Comment: Why? Because it makes your code ugly and overly complex. This isn't java :)

Comment: Whoa, talking about hammers... :)

Comment: I think it is neater and also a lot simpler to debug. Also you add the power of the compiler to check that you have not made a mistake of not adding inappropriate functions to your array.

Comment: @Ed Oh, never mind. I totally misread that. Silly comment deleted.

Comment: @NikBougalis - I delete my comment and nobody will never know!

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (*FUNC_PTR)(void);

FUNC_PTR funcs[3];

funcs[0] = func1;
funcs[1] = func2;
funcs[2] = func3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the signature of the functions are the same, you can Use function pointers

Comment: If the signatures are different, you're screwed.